# Generate 2-digit number in python that doesn't end in 1 or 8

Tags: python

I am trying to generate numbers that are between 12 and 77, excluding 21, 28, 31, 38, 41, 48 etc.
I could probably try using % and while loops but is there a quicker, more pythonic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like:

```
[n for n in range(12, 78) if repr(n)[-1] not in ('1', '8')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use generators and endswith() you can do as follows:

```
def gen(n1, n2, exclude):
    for i in range(n1, n2):
        if not str(i).endswith(exclude):
            yield i


for i in gen(12, 30, exclude=('1', '8')):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable increment that will make your number progress exactly to the desired values without generating unnecessary entries that you have to filter out.

```
n   = 12
while n<=77:
    print(n)
    n += 1 + (n%10 in (0,7))  # or: n += 2 - 0**(n%10%7)
        
12
13
14
15
16
17
19
20
22
23
24
25
26
27
29
30
32
...
69
70
72
73
74
75
76
77
```